# PHP unable to get class property

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and trying to create a basic class with several `protected` properties. I am able to set them using "magic" setter, however am not able to print the `name` property. I've read and this seems basic stuff, but for some odd reason the output is "name" instead the actual string I pass. The code is as follows:

```
    class Animal{
        protected $name;
        protected $color;
        protected $type;

        public function __set($attr, $value){
            switch ($attr){
                case "name":
                    $this->name = $attr;
                    break;

                case "color":
                    $this->color = $attr;
                    break;

                case "type":
                    $this->type = $attr;
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "attr not found in class";
            }

            printf ("set %s to %s <br>", $attr, $value);
        }

        public function __get($attr){
            if(property_exists($this, $attr)){
                return $this->$attr;
            }
        }

        public function run(){
            echo $this->name ." runs! <br>";
        }

        public function getName(){
            return $this->name."<br>";
        }
    }

$animal1 = new Animal();
$animal1->name = "Animal_1";
$animal1->color = "black";
$animal1->type = "common";

echo $animal1->getName();
echo $animal1->run();
echo $animal1->name;
```

This is the output:

```
set name to Animal_1 
set color to black 
set type to common 
name
name runs! 
name
```

Why can't I get the `name` property of the class and instead  just getting the name of the property itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
$this->name = $attr;
```

to:

```
$this->name = $value;
```

as $attr IS set to "name" according to your switch case, and I assume that $value is holding what you actually need.

The same thing would apply to the rest of your switch cases.

Comment: Thanks. I cant believe I did not notice that bug.

Answer (score 1):

You currently set the value of the property to its key:

```
$this->name = $attr;
```

Instead, set the value to `$value`:

```
$this->name = $value;
```

This will prevent any errors that may occur.

P.S.  I just now noticed that someone already posted the same solution.  Woops :)